# fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean

Tags: magento-1, localhost

It's not duplicated one I think.

Because what I found similar is a little different from the path.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean in /MagentoProject/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line 71
```

The code that error message says is that line :

```
$namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
```

How could I solve this? I didn't do anything...

I set the environment

1. brew install redis
2. brew install homebrew/php/php56
3. homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt homebrew/php/php56-opcache
       homebrew/php/php56-redis
4. Set virtual host 'ln -s
       ../sites-available/linkshops2 .'

Is there any specialist at magento who can help me and give me a solution?

UPDATE
the point of error is below function __construct()

```
public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer';
    if ($this->getCustomerConfigShare()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
    }

    $this->init($namespace);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this problem is with local.xml configuration's file. I had the same problem I fixed creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

i searche and found many of the websites this issue is due to compilation.

please visit bellow link for more info.

[Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in ;](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54512/error-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getcode-on-a-non-object-in)

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: and also print_r($namespace). the value you get is proper or not.

Comment: Denish,please donot put link as answer

Comment: i think redundant answer should not be there in site. so i post link which i follow and got solution.

Comment: Please post the relevant information from the link, in case it goes offline.

Comment: @denishvachhani Thank you, I'm trying now. I have a question, the link you posted has a little different path from me... did you have also a different path error but could solve that error by reading that post ?